# Almost everywhere convergence and $L^p$ probability

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, pointwise-convergence

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$ be a probability space. If $X_n \leq C$ for each $n\geq 1$ and $X_n \to X$ almost everywhere, prove that $X_n \to X$ in $L^p$.

So far I have just showed that $X, X_n \in L^p$. For the $L^p$ convergence I have just used the DCT to write $\int_{\Omega}X_n dP \to \int_{\Omega}X dP$, but don't know what else to do.

Comment: This  is false. If you change $X_n \leq C$ to $|X_n| \leq C$ then it becomes true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

As stated by the comment below the question, it is not true unless you have $|X_n| \le C$ instead.

If we assume that, apply the DCT to
$$\int_\Omega |X_n-X|^p dP$$

Comment: As stated by OP the result is false.

Comment: Ho, yes you are correct, I have edited.

Comment: @nicomezi: Thanks. I got it (when $|X_n| \leq C$), but what is a counterexample for the case $X_n \leq C$?

Comment: I dont have the example in mind (I think you can find it quite easily on some books) but the problem here is that $X_n$ can go to $- \infty$.

Comment: I think I have it. Define $P(X_n=0)=1-1/n$ and $P(X_n=-n)=1/n$ and $X=0$ a.s. . $X_n$ converges a.s. to $0$ but $X_n$ does not converge to $X$ in $L^p$ since $E([X_n-X|^p)=-n^p\times1/n$.